# Blazor server app still authorized even after altering cookies

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity, blazor-server-side, asp.net-authorization

I have tested a sample Blazor server application that uses standard ASP.NET Core Identity and I logged in successfully.

But even after I tried to alter the cookies manually from the dev tools while being signed in, I can still navigate freely through the application pages.
Only when I <strike>hard reload</strike> press the refresh button on the browser and reload the page, I get redirected to the login page.

Doesn't ASP.NET Identity check authorization state on every request on Blazor or it just checks it only on the initial load? or do I miss something?

Comment: which cookie did you try to delete?

Comment: i have cleared all cookies but i can still browse the application until refresh the page

Comment: You can capture the network traffic when you call ato the server and aee which authorization header is sent, and then look for it in the cookies.., maybe it was saved in local storage

Comment: Are you browsing browser cached pages? Use the Chrome debugger to check page load status when browsing.